# How to use variable from link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link which reads

```
<a href="<%= user_collections_path(@user, :status => "Got") %>">Collection</a>
```

and another which reads

```
<a href="<%= user_collections_path(@user, :status => "Want") %>">Wantlist</a>
```

They link to the same view but produce different lists.
On that view page I want to be able to alter the text depending on if it is a Collection or Wantlist page. Something like this:

```
<% if :status == 'Got' %>collection<% elsif :status == 'Want' %>wantlist<% end %>
```

Obviously that doesn't work but after much experimentation I can't work out how to query which status was passed in the link. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing it like this

```
<% if params[:status] == 'Got' %>Collection

<% elsif params[:status] == 'Want' %>Wantlist

<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah, so params is what makes it look in the parameters passed in the link? Thank you thank you.

Comment: @WorldOfProper Yes! `params` is the magic word which you need here.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you pass to `link_to` get put into the `params` hash. Here, `params[:status]` is how you'd access it, either in the view or - better - in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

[link_to_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) might be alternate solution for your question.

```
link_to_if(params[:status] == 'got', "Collection", user_collections_path(@user)) do
   link_to "Wantlist" user_collections_path(@user)
end
```

Comment: He didn't asked that! He wants how to alter the `text` on view page with respect to the `status`.

Comment: Yes I'll have both links at all times as they are alternatives. Thank you for introducing me to like_to_if though, that's very handy.

Comment: @Pavan I said **alternate solution** above, not exact solution. I suggest to check my answer again. Plus, no need to have an exlamation mark.